# rc circuit for electrical noise: why are these circuits similar?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I am studying about thevnin's Theorem but i having an issue understanding why this two circuits are the same.  I get that when you short out the AC voltage, the circuits are basically wired the same way but i get lost when i take the switch into account.  For the second circuit wouldn't you be shorting out the RC when you turn on the switch?

Comment: Replace the source with a short and connect the two ground symbols. Them compare the circuits again.

Comment: They look different to me.  Where did you find that they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

In both the circuits, shorting the AC source and the switch in ON position, make both RC and L shorted. Thevenin eq. impedance is zero in both the cases, when looking from Vo end.